# Why I can not place two figures next to each other?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to display two figures next to each other. To do so, I used this webpage http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures for reference, but it didn't work.
Instead of this, they are displayed one above the other, which I really dont want. Any help?
This is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {img/} }
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
%\newtheorem{thm1}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\usepackage{float}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\newcommand{\euler}{e}
\newcommand{\firstName}{Name1 }
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newcounter{claimcounter}
%\numberwithin{claimcounter}{thm}
%\newenvironment{claim}[1]{\par\noindent\underline{Claim:}\space#1}{}
%\newenvironment{claimproof}[1]{\par\noindent\underline{Proof:}\space#1}{\hfill $\blacksquare$}
\newenvironment{claim}{\stepcounter{claimcounter}{Claim \theclaimcounter:}}{}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Name}

\maketitle

\tikzset{%
   point/.style = {fill=black,inner sep=1pt, circle, minimum width=3pt,align=right,rotate=60},
   } 
\tikzstyle{weight} = [font=\scriptsize]  
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=blue!20]

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother


\section{section}
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah

\begin{figure}
 \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
 \resizebox{0.7\textwidth}{!}{
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,auto=left]
  \node[vertex] (v1) at (1,10)  {$a$};
  \node[vertex] (v2) at (1,8)  {$b$};
  \node[vertex] (v3) at (1,6)  {$c$};
  \node[vertex] (v4) at (8,10)  {$d$};
  \node[vertex] (v5) at (8,8)   {$e$};


  \begin{scope}[every edge/.style={draw=black}]
    \draw  (v4) edge  (v1);
    \draw  (v4) edge  (v2);
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}[every edge/.style={draw=red}]
    \draw  (v5) edge (v1);
    \draw  (v5) edge (v3);
   \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 }

 \caption{I want this figure to be displayed to the left}
    \label{fig:1}
    \end{subfigure}
%\end{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\resizebox{0.7\textwidth}{!}{
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,auto=right]
  \node[vertex] (v1) at (1,10)  {$a$};
  \node[vertex] (v2) at (1,8)  {$b$};
  \node[vertex] (v3) at (1,6)  {$c$};
  \node[vertex] (v4) at (1,4)  {$d$};
  \node[vertex] (v5) at (1,2)  {$e$};
  \node[vertex] (v6) at (1,0)  {$f$};
  \node[vertex] (v7) at (8,8)  {$g$};
  \node[vertex] (v8) at (8,3)   {$h$};


 \draw[->] (v1)--(v7);
 \draw[->] (v2)--(v7);
 \draw[->] (v3)--(v7);
 \draw[->] (v4)--(v7);
 \draw[->] (v1)--(v8);
 \draw[->] (v5)--(v8);

 \end{tikzpicture}
 }
 \caption{I want this figure to be displayed to the right}
    \label{fig:2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to replace `0.7` by `0.45`.

Comment: You mustn't have blank lines between `\end{subfigure}` and `\begin{subfigure}`.

Comment: @cfr The subfigures are `0.3\textwidth` each. Inside `subfigure`, `\textwidth` refers to the specified size for the subfigure.

Comment: @egreg I always thought only `\linewidth` did that...

Comment: Note that in the question marked as duplicate, `minipage` is used instead of `subcaption`, but it's really the same thing.

Comment: @egreg, Thanks a lot! Now it works. I have another question now: since the two figures are too close to each other, how should insert more space between them?

Comment: Add `\hspace{4em}%` after `\end{subcaption}`, or any length you like